# Java Mail: Create Message from String

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a `String` containing an email with attachments.

*(The whole `String` is about 2000 lines long, so here are only the main parts.)*

*Start* of the `String`:

```
--_002_0BB5B2121E0AF543BC9F9664030EF5991ADD1C89SWBNTSRV26sorec_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html xmlns:v=3D"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o=3D"urn:schemas-micr=
osoft-com:office:office" ......
```

*End of the mail content and start of an attachment*:

```
</div>
</body>
</html>

--_002_0BB5B2121E0AF543BC9F9664030EF5991ADD1C89SWBNTSRV26sorec_
Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="IMAG0205.jpg"
Content-Description: IMAG0205.jpg
...
/9j/4TokRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACAEPAAIAAABcAAAAbgEQAAIAAABcAAAAy... (base64 file)
```

So now I need to parse this very long `String` to a `javax.mail.MultiPart` or leave it as a `String` if the mail does not have any attachments. 
 **NOTE:** I have no chance to receive the mail directly as a `MultiPart`, I only have this `String`.

This is what I have so far:

```
/**
 * Return the primary text content of the message.
 */
private boolean textIsHtml = false;

private String getText(Part p) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    if (p.getContent() instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
        ByteArrayInputStream stream = (ByteArrayInputStream) p.getContent(); // This ByteArrayInputStream contains the long String mentioned in this question.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session, stream); // here I try to create a MimeMessage from that String, but this doesn't work.
        p = message;
    }
    if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
        String s = (String) p.getContent();
        textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
        return s;
    }

    if (p.isMimeType("multipart/alternative")) {
        // prefer html text over plain text
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
        String text = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
            Part bp = mp.getBodyPart(i);
            if (bp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                if (text == null) {
                    text = getText(bp);
                }
                continue;
            } else if (bp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                String s = getText(bp);
                if (s != null) {
                    return s;
                }
            } else {
                return getText(bp);
            }
        }
        return text;
    } else if (p.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
        Multipart mp = (Multipart) p.getContent();
        for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
            String s = getText(mp.getBodyPart(i));
            if (s != null) {
                return s;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The code example is the code from [the official Oracle FAQ page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#mainbody), but a bit modified to convert the `Object` provided by `getContent()` to a new `MimeMessage`. The code does not work because the created `MimeMessage` has mime-type `text/html` instead of `multipart/*`. 
So a ClassCastException is thrown when executing these lines after the first if-block:

```
    if (p.isMimeType("text/*")) {
        String s = (String) p.getContent();
        textIsHtml = p.isMimeType("text/html");
        return s;
    }
```

Does anyone has a smart idea on how to parse the `String` without writing huge parsers?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: parsing on what?Pls upload example string

Comment: @constantlearner I'll upload an example String for you on wednesday. Thank's for your comment. I thought it would be clear if I say that the String contains the email and the attachments. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

Your example string is NOT an entire message, it appears to be only the multipart body of the message.  Assuming the string is **always** a multipart, you'll want to use the MimeMultipart constructor that takes a DataSource.  You'll need to create your own DataSource implementation that returns an InputStream where the bytes come from the string.  Your DataSource implementation will also need to return a ContentType string that includes the "boundary" parameter for the multipart content; or you'll need to set the System property "mail.mime.multipart.ignoremissingboundaryparameter" to "true"; see the [javadocs for the javax.mail.internet package](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/package-summary.html).

With all of that you should be able to use the example code from the JavaMail FAQ.

If your string is not always a multipart, you're going to need access to the Content-Type header from the original message.  Without that, you're pretty much screwed.

It's only fair to ask at this point why you're getting this string in a way that makes dealing with it so difficult.  Why not save the entire original MIME message content instead of just the body of the message?  Are you using JavaMail to extract/save this string to begin with?

Answer (score 0):

If you have something that can be parsed into a `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage`, you're better off using Apache commons-email, which has a very handy `MimeMessageParser` utility class that can be used for extracting the body text from an HTML MIME part or plain text part.

You can then write a helper method like this:

```
private String extractContentFromMail(String rawMessage) throws Exception {
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session, new ByteArrayInputStream(rawMessage.getBytes()));

    MimeMessageParser parser = new MimeMessageParser(msg);
    parser.parse();
    if (parser.hasHtmlContent()) {
        log.debug("extracted mail with HTML content.");
        return parser.getHtmlContent();
    } else {
        log.debug("extracted mail with plaintext content.");
        return parser.getPlainContent();
    }
}
```